# Puxar dados fixos do .json para select no form

Tags: jquery, json, select, formulário

Não sei o que está errado que não está puxando os dados do json, meu objetivo é puxar os dados cidade/bairro para exibir atraves de um outro código javascript, porém não consigo fazer o select exibir as cidades e os bairros que estão no arquivo json.

**Código javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


    $(document).ready(function () {

                        $.getJSON('cidade_bairro.json', function (data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data))

                            var items = [];
            var options = '<option value="">Escolha uma cidade</option>';   

            $.each(!data, function (key, val) {
                options == '<option value="' + val.nome + '">' + val.nome + '</option>';
            });                 
            $("#cidades").html(options);                

            $("#cidades").change(function () {              

                var options_cidades = '';
                                    var options_bairros = '';
                var str = "";                   

                $("#cidades option:selected").each(function () {
                    str += $(this).text();
                });

                $.each(!data, function (key, val) {
                    if(val.nome == str) {                           
                        $.each(val.cidades, function (key_city, val_city) {
                            options_cidades += '<option value="' + val_city + '">' + val_city + '</option>';
                        });                         
                    }
                });
                            }).change();

              $("#bairros").html(options);

              $("#bairros").change(function () {

              $("#bairros option:selected").each(function () {
                                        str += $(this).text();
                                    });

                                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                                        if(val.nome == str) {
                                            $.each(val.bairros, function (key_neighborhood, val_neighborhood){
                                                options_bairros += '<option value="' + val_neighborhood +'">' + val_neighborhood + '</option>';
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });

            }).change();        

        });

    });

</script>
```

**Código HTML**

```
    <!-- Cidade -->
    <select id="cidades">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
            <!-- Bairros -->
    <select id="bairros">
                <option value=""></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55915/discussion-on-question-by-marvin-edge-puxar-dados-fixos-do-json-para-select-no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, eu não entendi muito bem o que você está tentando fazer, mas segue o código para listar os bairros de uma cidade.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
var str = ""
                        $.getJSON('/cidade_bairro.json', function (data) { 


                            var items = [];
            var options = '<option value="">Escolha uma cidade</option>';   

            $.each(data[0].bairro, function (key, val) {
                $("#cidades").append($('<option>', {
                    value: val,
                    text: val
                }));
            });                 

            $("#cidades").change(function () {              

                var options_cidades = '';
                                    var options_bairros = '';
                var str = "";                   

                $("#cidades option:selected").each(function () {
                    str += $(this).text();
                });

                $.each(!data, function (key, val) {
                    if(val.nome == str) {                           
                        $.each(val.cidades, function (key_city, val_city) {
                            options_cidades += '<option value="' + val_city + '">' + val_city + '</option>';
                        });                         
                    }
                });
                            }).change();

              $("#bairros").html(options);

              $("#bairros").change(function () {

              $("#bairros option:selected").each(function () {
                                        str += $(this).val();
                                    });

                                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                                        if(val.nome == str) {
                                            $.each(val.bairros, function (key_neighborhood, val_neighborhood){
                                                options_bairros += '<option value="' + val_neighborhood +'">' + val_neighborhood + '</option>';
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });

            }).change();        

        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="cidades">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
            <!-- Bairros -->
    <select id="bairros">
                <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```